# Gemfileでのgemのインストールができません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Macbook airでRuby on Railsの開発をしております。
Ruby on Rails チュートリアル(http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/static-pages?version=4.0#code-pages_controller_spec_title)
の3章を勉強中ですが、GemFileにGemを追加してbundle install --without productionするとエラーが出ています。
エラーの内容は下記の通りです。

[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.
You specified: sass-rails (= 5.0) and sass-rails (>= 5.0.0). Bundler cannot continue.

#  from /Users/xxx/rails_projects/sample_app/Gemfile:42
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
　>  gem 'sass-rails', '>=5.0.0'
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------

バージョンが違ってそうなのか、または「>=」このような記号が間違ってるのかと思って色々と変えながら試してみましたが全部同じエラーが出ています。
一体何が原因でこれを解消するにはどうすればいいんでしょうか？

ちなみに開発環境はるrubyのバージョンは2.2.1p85　railsのバージョンは4.2.4でrbenvを使っております。
Ruby on Rails チュートリアルの環境はrubyは2.0.0 Railsは4.0.5でRVMを使っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Gemfile: You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.

エラーには上記のようにあるので、Gemfile内で、`sass-rails` gem を複数回、異なるバージョンで指定しているのではないでしょうか？